# Не получается создать таблицу в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

[1-я ошибка]      https://wampi.ru/image/6oeM9bx

[2-я ошибка]      https://wampi.ru/image/6oeiiQH

```
    <?php

    $issetName = isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']);
    $issetAuthor = isset($_POST['author']) && !empty($_POST['author']); //этими 2-мя строками проверяем установку переменных

    $result = false; //получить неверное значение
    $doSendRequest = false; // не делать повторный запрос

    if($issetName && $issetAuthor) { // если переменные установлены

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $author = $_POST['author']; //указываем переменные

        $mysqlHost = 'localhost'; //типо хоста, и он тут локальный
        $mysqlUser = 'root'; //имя пользователя
        $mysqlUserPassword = ''; //пароль
        $dbName = 'thismovie'; //имя этой БД

        $mysqli = @new mysqli($mysqlHost, $mysqlUser, $mysqlUserPassword, $dbName); //устанавливает БД и ее значения

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            die('Ошибка соединения: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
        } //на случай ошибки обрубает запрос

        $mysqli->set_charset('utf8'); //установка соединения

        $query = "INSERT INTO `music1` (`id`, `name`, `author`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$author');"; //это типо главной задачи

        $result = $mysqli->query( $query ); //в резулбтате добавить значения в табблицу
        $doSendRequest = true; //сделать повторный запрос

        $mysqli->close(); //закрыть запрос
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Домашка</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php if($result && $doSendRequest) : ?>
        <h3>Композиция успешно сохранена!</h3>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(!$result && $doSendRequest) : ?>
        <h3>При сохранении композиции произошла ошибка!</h3>
    <?php endif; ?>

  <form action="player.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="название композиции"><br>
    <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="исполнитель"><br>    
    <input type="submit" value="добавить">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я делаю то же самое, что и в уроке, но при нажатии кнопки сохранить вылетает ошибка, а если перезагрузить страницу и кликнуть на таблицу categories то выходит уже другая ошибка

Comment: Код PHP тут причём? У вас проблемы в phpmyadmin. Какой запрос там выполняете? Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: никакого запроса я не делаю, просто по кнопкам в phpmyadminпытаюсь создать таблицу